# How to pass a function as a property to lit element?

Tags: lit-element

I have the following lit web component

```
<my-element></my-element>
```

Inside my-element is a button that should call the parent web component test function when clicked.

How can I do this using lit elements?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by directly setting the property on `my-element` using [Property Expressions](https://lit.dev/docs/templates/expressions/#property-expressions).

For example, in the block of code below. `my-element` has a property `onPress`. The `parent-el` can set the property directly by setting `.onPress=${/* Function */}`.

This is a declarative alternative to the following that could be put in the parent element:

```js
this.shadowRoot.querySelector('my-element').onPress = () => console.log('pressed');
```

Full example:

```js
@customElement('parent-el')
export class ParentEl extends LitElement {
  render() {
    return html`<my-element
      .onPress=${() => console.log('called')
    }></my-element>`;
  }
}


@customElement('my-element')
export class MyEl extends LitElement {
  @property()
  onPress = () => {};
  
  render () {
    return html`<button @click="${this.onPress}">Call passed function</button>`;
  }
}
```

And live example: https://lit.dev/playground/#gist=5da1cb16373f7fca9c8a7cbdc5a22e4a